# Style sheet and Images missing on a html project

Tags: html, css, npm, visual-studio-code, sass

I have a weird issue. I have a website project that I am currently working and I am am using node sass. While in the IDE, I am using VS Code, everything is fine and the styles are there. If I open the html file outside of the VS Code the css disappears for some reason. The css gets compiled fine and the .css file is there. The link tag points to it just fine, but no styles and no images either. Have I missed something in the setup of my project that would cause these issues when opening the html file externally?

Comment: Use the Network tab in the Dev Tools to see if these files are loaded and from which URL

Comment: Make sure that your main.scss file is compiling, you have body tags in your html file, and that you are linking the .css file, not the .scss one (check page source to make sure your files are being loaded in). Something else you can try is clearing your browser cache.

Comment: The css file is definitely linked, not the scss. The file does not seem to be loading. The network tab shows nothing. It is curious that the files load just fine in vs code with live sever but i get nothing outside.

Comment: What kind of server do you use outside VSC? what is the link href text?